Counting maximal subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_m^n$

Let 
$$
\mathbb{Z}_m=\mathbb{Z} / m\mathbb{Z}
$$
How many maximal subgroups does 
$$
\mathbb{Z}_m^n=\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_m \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_m}_n
$$ 
have? (m need not to be a prime and that is the difference from On the numbers of maximal subgroups of a $p$-group)

Where $m$ is not prime, $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is no longer a field. Is there any possible way to count maximal subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_m^n$?

What makes you "suggest that the number of the subgroup of order 5 of $;\mathbb{Z}_5^{15}$ equals the number of the maximal subgroups"? (This is true but not obvious.)

Perhaps this is a bit overpower, but Syllow's theorems do the job.

@AnneBauval Intuitively, a subgroup of order 5 is a bit like a 'complement' of a maximal subgroup, and maybe this can be explained by linear algebra.

Exactly. Does this answer your question? On the numbers of maximal subgroups of a $p$-group

@AnnelBauval From the post you quote, the answer from spin actually solves my second question (and I think the answer from mesel is not correct because we cannot define a inner vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ from my perspective). But anyway the other questions have not beed answered. Is there any possible way to count where p is not prime?

@ajotatxe Can you explain it more clearly? I do not think Sylow's theorems do work.

Every maximal subgroup has prime index, so you just need to count in each Sylow subgroup.


I didn't receive your notification because of its misprint. 2) Mesel's answer (formalising your intuition) was correct (just replace "inner product" by "canonical pairing", i.e. $(u,v)\mapsto\sum u_kv_k$). 3) I voted to reopen your (drastically modified) post, but it will be easier to read if you remove your (now obsolete) example with $\mathbb{Z}_5^{15}$. Even better if you moreover replace $p$ by $m$ everywhere, even in the title.


This is an interesting question. I've got an intuition that a maximal subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{p^m}^n$ corresponds to a $\mathbb Z_{p^m}$-matrix whose determinant has exactly one $p$ in its prime factorization :)

I think the number of maximal subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{p^m}^n$ is $\frac{p^{nm}-p^{n(m-1)}}{p^m-p^{m-1}}$. idk if i'm right :) Editing my answer...

I see that I'm not right:) see the answer below, it's not so difficult

Suppose $m=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\dots p_n^{e_k}$(prime factorization), then we have $$\mathbb Z_m^n\cong \sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb Z_{{p_i}^{e_i}}^n:=\sum_{i=1}^kG_i$$where the $\sum$'s denote direct sum. For each $i\ne j$, $\gcd (|G_i|, |G_j|)=1$, so every subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb Z_m^n$ has the form $H_1 \oplus H_2 \oplus \dots \oplus H_k$, where each $H_i$ is a subgroup of $G_i$. If $H$ is a maximal subgroup, then $k-1$ $H_i$'s will be forced to be equal to their corresponding $G_i$'s, while the remaining $H_i$ will be a maximal subgroup of its $G_i$. Hence, if we denote the number of maximal subgroups of a group $G$ by $f(G)$, we have
$$f(\mathbb Z_m^n)=\sum_{i=1}^kf(G_i)=\sum_{i=1}^kf(\mathbb Z_{{p_i}^{e_i}}^n)$$
We have reduced the problem to the case $m=p^k$, as ajotatxe and Steve D commented.

Now we are going to compute $f(\mathbb Z_{p^k}^n)$.
Since $\mathbb Z_{p^k}^n$ is a finite $p$-group, we can compute its Frattini subgroup: $\Phi(G)=G^{p}[G,G]=\mathbb Z_{p^{k-1}}^n$. By the Correspondence Theorem, a maximal subgroup of $G$ actually corresponds to a maximal subgroup of $G/\Phi(G)\cong \mathbb Z_p^n$. So $f(\mathbb Z_{p^k}^n)$ is essentially the same as $f(\mathbb Z_{p}^n)$, which is $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$.

(If you don't believe the result, try computing it directly, you'll find it shows the same answer:)

I have checked that with GAP, and the result shows that you are correct! (Btw, no group theory beginner knows the Frattini subgroup, my friend :) )

We don't need Frattini subgroups. Since $\mathbb Z_{p^k}^n$ is abelian, let's appeal to the facts that in a finite abelian $p$-group (i) the maximal subgroups are the index-$p$ subgroups and (ii) the number of subgroups of index $p$ and order $p$ are equal. (More generally, the number of subgroups with index $r$ and order $r$ are equal for any $r$.) So we count subgroups of order $p$. In $\mathbb Z_{p^k}^n$ the elements of order $p$ are nonzero elements in $(p^{k-1}\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z)^n$, so there are $p^n-1$ elements with order $p$ and thus $(p^n-1)/(p-1)$ subgroups with order $p$.
